# Populating a drop down on register page ASP.NET Core 3.1 Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

When I try to follow tutorials and things about populating a drop down menu, it requires me putting some lines of code into the controller for the page, but I am unable to scaffold or find the identity controller to do this on the register page and use a drop down.

How would I go about either finding this file or doing the drop down another way so I can still use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core provides ASP.NET Core Identity as a Razor Class Library. Applications that include Identity can apply the scaffolder to selectively add the source code contained in the Identity Razor Class Library (RCL). You might want to generate source code so you can modify the code and change the behavior :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

1. From Solution Explorer, right-click on the `project > Add > New Scaffolded Item`
2. From the left pane of the Add Scaffold dialog, select `Identity > Add`.
3. Choose Files to override ,For example , Register related : Account\Register .
4. Select your data context class : `ApplicationDbContext` by default .
5. Click `Add` button.

Now if you want to modify the login UI , you can modify relevant page in `your project --> Areas-->Identity -->Pages-->Account -->Register.cshtml` page . If you want to modify the Register page to add dropdownlist , you can refer to below code sample for building select lists in Razor Pages :

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists